# CUDA Visual Profiler 'Interactive' X config option?

Tags: cuda, profiler, config

I get the following warning when launching an application in computeprof on Ubuntu 11.04:

> The selected counter(s) "gld instructions 8bit", "gld instructions 16bit", "gld instructions 32bit", "gld instructions 64bit", "gld instructions 128bit", "gst instructions 8bit", "gst instructions 16bit", "gst instructions 32bit", "gst instructions 64bit", "gst instructions 128bit" can cause GPU kernels to run longer than the driver's watchdog timeout limit. In this case the driver will terminate the GPU kernel resulting in an application error and the profiling data will not be available. Setting the X Config option 'Interactive' to false is recommended when these counters are selected.

Where do I set this config option?

I am also not getting any counts for 64b and 128b loads and stores when profiling an app on Ubuntu, whereas I see them when I run the profiler on OS X.  Is the 'Interactive' config option also affecting this?  Note that the kernels do not appear to be timing out; they complete well before the default timeout of 30 seconds.

This is CUDA 4.0.17 on Ubuntu and 4.0.19 on OS X.

Answer (score 12):

this option can be set in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Just add `Option         "Interactive" "0"` to the device section of your GPU. Here is what my device section looks like:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460"
    Option         "Interactive" "0"
EndSection
```

I run the same version of CUDA in ubuntu but I'm using OpenCL. Profiling with one of these instructions causes high CPU usage and never finishes (I have to kill the process) - even when interactive mode is disabled. Anyways, you can give it a try.

Also make sure to verify the compute capability of your GPU and check if the requested count is supported : [Visual Profiler User Guide](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/VisualProfiler/Compute_Visual_Profiler_User_Guide.pdf&rct=j&q=Compute%20visual%20profiler%20guide&ei=6h1VTpSCNMyXOvrq-ZwG&usg=AFQjCNGZYsxg0Y-Z9wHTm7XBXIh58utkrA&cad=rja). Although it seems that this is not the cause of you problem since it's working in OS X.

Comment: What about if there is no xorg.conf file in my computer? should i create it or is there another way around?

Comment: Does one have to restart the nvidia driver or computer etc after doing this?

Comment: Thanks - this is working now: `optirun --no-xorg ./a.out`