# How to disable or change the timeout limit for the GPU under linux?

Tags: linux, timeout, limit, gpu

Does anybody know how to disable or change the timeout limit for CUDA kernels under Ubuntu 12.10?
(With current versions of Windows one can set the timeout limit in the registry.)

Please tell me as well if there is no possibility to do this with Ubuntu.

The only results of my previous search are the following:

- running the CUDA kernel without a graphical display is attached to the GPU
- splitting the kernel into smaller ones to avoid exceeding the time limit

Both solutions are no option for me because I need the graphical display
for my application and there are already no threads running sequently after
another during the kernel is executed. And splitting the single threads will
cost months of work. Please do not ask further for the details in these
directions.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the watchdog by modifying your Xorg config ([`Option Interactive "0"`](http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/270.41.06/README/xconfigoptions.html#Interactive)). An example is available in the answer to this question: [CUDA Visual Profiler 'Interactive' X config option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906579/cuda-visual-profiler-interactive-x-config-option)

Comment: What about if there is no xorg.conf file in my computer? should i create it or is there another way around?

Comment: @FedericoGentile Yes, if there's no xorg.conf, you should create one. Either /etc/xorg.conf, or (better) /etc/xorg.conf.d/80-cuda.conf (or something similar).

Comment: @FedericoGentile (Old I know.) I ran `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and got a basic conf file to edit. (By basic I mean it matches my actual hardware, but nothing else extra.)

Comment: Should this also work for a Tesla GPGPU without graphics sockets?