# Preventing kernel timeout on second cuda device (no screen attached)

Tags: timeout, cuda

Sorry if this already solved, but all answers read so far refers to the GPU attached to a screen ([for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497685/how-do-you-get-around-the-maximum-cuda-run-time)

How the "kernel execution timeout" can be disabled on a card *not* attached to any screen?
My "second" gpu card shows that flag is "on" when queried.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not help, but try unchecking the second card in NVIDIA Control Panel | Set Up Multiple Displays | Select the displays you want to use. Also, try setting your second card up as a PhysX device under Set PhysX Configuration.