# How to shut graphic card output signal but still link it for CUDA? (it is a geforce)

Tags: cuda, nvidia

for using CUDA on PC's graphic card(usually single card), it's known that windows or linux will reset the graphic card if the card lost response for 5 sec or 2 sec(depending on OS version,this mechanism is called Timeout detection recovery,TDR).

msdn says a graphic card giving output signal will be restricted by TDR in case that video signal by graphic card is interrupted.

if windows does that, my CUDA program (takes much longer than 2 or 5 sec running on the graphic card)cannot be completed.

so as to avoid this, i enabled the onboard graphic card(biostar HD 880G Mainboard),attach monitor to onboard graphic card.

the system now recognised both graphic cards(NV gtx 460 and onboard AMD HD4250), but the 2 sec restriction on gtx 460 is still there. i switched my monitor on both graphic card, both cards give output signal.

How can I make the independent graphic card stop giving video signal(or stop OS giving it signal), but still links to system?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/hardware/ff569918(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812707/preventing-kernel-timeout-on-second-cuda-device-no-screen-attached