# CUDA - nvidia driver crash while running

Tags: crash, cuda, driver

I run a raytracer in CUDA with N Bounces (each ray will bounce N times).

I view the results using openGL.

once N is small (1~4) everything works great. once i make N big (~10) each thread (about 800x1000) has to do a lot of computing and this when the screen goes black, and than back on, with the note that my nvidia crash.

i searched online and think now that what cause it some sort of a watch-dog timer since i use the same graphic card for my display and my computing (computing takes more than 2 sec so the driver reset itself).

is there a command to make the host (cpu) WAIT for the device(gpu) for as long as it takes?

what do i need to do? im stuck :(

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, you are running on Windows Vista or Windows 7.  Windows operating systems have a watchdog timer, as you guessed.  The watchdog timer only applies to GPUs with displays attached.

The easiest solution is to run 2 or more GPUs, and run CUDA on GPU(s) without a display attached.

You can disable the watchdog timer.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497685/how-doyou-get-around-the-maximum-cuda-run-time) for more details.  However you should do so with care—remember that when you have a long running kernel on your primary display GPU you will make your computer completely unresponsive (at least you won't be able to see what it is doing) until the kernel completes.

Comment: Oh My God!!! U saved my day!

what i did was adding to the registry (using "regedit") the following DWORDS:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicDrivers\ [added "TdrLevel=0" and "TdrDelay=10"] 

&&

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicDrivers\Timeout [changed "Timeout" value to 0x60]