# Disable Nvidia watchdog with OpenCL on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, opencl, xcode4.3, nvidia

I have a OpenCL program which runs fine for small problems but when running larger problems exceeds the 8-10s time limit for running kernels on Nvidia hardware. Although I have no monitors attached to the GPU I am computing on (Nvidia GTX580), the kernel will always be terminated once it runs for around 8-10s.

The preliminary research I did on this problem indicates that the Nvidia watchdog should only enforce the time limit if a monitor is connected to the graphics card. However I do not have any monitors connected to the GPU the OpenCl is running on yet this limit is still enforced.

Is it possible to disable the Nvidia watchdog or get the drivers to recognise that no monitors are attached to the GTX580 in Mac OS X 10.7.4?

I am aware that a possible way around this is to break up into smaller kernels however due to the nature of my work I could still hit this limit when I go more fine grain.

The system I am compiling/running on is as follows :

- MacPro4,1 2 x 2.26 GHz Quad Core Intel Xeon
- Mac OS X 10.7.4
- XCode 4.3.3
- Nvidia GT120 (2 Monitors attached)
- NVidia GTX580 (Nothing attached)

For extra information when I run the NVidia device query I get the following output :

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Found 2 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 580"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          4.2 / 4.2
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 1536 MBytes (1610285056 bytes)
  (16) Multiprocessors x ( 32) CUDA Cores/MP:    512 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1564 MHz (1.56 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 786432 bytes
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(65536), 2D=(65536,65535), 3D=(2048,2048,2048)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(16384) x 2048, 2D=(16384,16384) x 2048
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 65535
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           6 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

Device 1: "GeForce GT 120"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          4.2 / 4.2
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 512 MBytes (536543232 bytes)
  ( 4) Multiprocessors x (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:    32 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1400 MHz (1.40 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             800 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(8192), 2D=(65536,32768), 3D=(2048,2048,2048)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(8192) x 512, 2D=(8192,8192) x 512
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 8192
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  768
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    512 x 512 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 1
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   No
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           5 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 4.2, CUDA Runtime Version = 4.2, NumDevs = 2, Device = GeForce GTX 580, Device = GeForce GT 120
[deviceQuery] test results...
PASSED

> exiting in 3 seconds: 3...2...1...done!
```

Comment: Have you checked messages in Console.app? Is anything posted there when your kernel is terminated?

Comment: @Kentzo in console.app I get NVDA(Compute): CHannel exception! exception type = 0x8 = FiFo: Watchdog Timeout Error

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Have you tried to ask this question on the apple dev forum?

Comment: @kentzo: this is not a bug, it is expected behavior. All display drivers contain a watchdog to stop rogue shaders or compute jobs from stalling the gpu and locking up the gui. Linux and Windows are exactly the same. There is no work-around for display gpus that I am aware of.

Comment: I think this has been answered already. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272513/cuda-nvidia-driver-crash-while-running