# thrust::system::system_error in transform_reduce

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am running a monte carlo simulation using Thrust on an Nvidia card with 2.1 compute capability.  If I try to transform_reduce the whole device_vector at once, I get the following error. Its not a matter of using up the memory on device because the vectors are that big (~1-10mb).  I know my code is right because it works if I compile with openmp and run on the host only. What can be causing this problem?

Unhandled exception at 0x776e15de in mccva.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x0014cb28.

But if I do the transform_reduce in chunks it works fine until I scale the number of timesteps in the simulation which it then gives the same error.

```
//run the Monte Carlo simulation
zpath * norm_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&z[0]);
cout << "initialized raw pointer" << endl;
thrust::device_vector<ctrparty> devctrp = ctrp;
assert(devctrp.size()==ctrp.size());
cout << "Initialized device vector" << endl;
cout << "copied host vec to device vec" << endl;

float cva = 0;
for(unsigned int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if(i<4)
        cva += (1-R) * thrust::transform_reduce(devctrp.begin()+i*2000, devctrp.begin() + (i+1)*2000 - 1, calc(norm_ptr, dt, r, sims, N), 0.0f, sum());
    else
        cva += (1-R) * thrust::transform_reduce(devctrp.begin()+i*2000, devctrp.begin() + (i+1)*2000, calc(norm_ptr, dt, r, sims, N), 0.0f, sum());
}
```

I get the error when I try this:

```
float cva = 0.0f;
try
{
    cva = thrust::transform_reduce(devctrp.begin(), devctrp.end(), calc(norm_ptr, dt, r, sims, N), 0.0f, sum()); //get the simulated CVA
}
catch(thrust::system_error e)
{
    printf(e.what());
}
```

I'm using VS2010 and when it breaks at the errors it points to the following in the dbgheap.c file.

```
__finally {
    /* unlock the heap
     */
    _munlock(_HEAP_LOCK);
}
```

Comment: what are the definitions of `calc()` and `sum()` ?  One of those may be the issue.  You could try doing just a `thrust::transform` with `calc` and just a `thrust::reduce` with `sum()` to see if you can narrow down the source of the error.  For instance, `norm_ptr` points to the device array `z`.  I don't know how `calc` uses it exactly, but if it is indexing through `z` in some fashion, then perhaps when you increase the length of the transform, you're running into trouble there.  It's just speculation, but it would help to see a more complete description of what you are doing in the transform

Comment: Are you building the debug or release version of the project?

Comment: I have checked that the calc and sum functions are working correctly by using printf within the functions.  What I see when using printf when transform_reducing the entire vector at once, is that it looks like it breaks it up into chunks itself as I see "calc" followed by "sum" followed by more "calc" and "sum" but it craps out somewhere along the way.  I'm using a debug version, I do have the -g and -G flags turned off.

Comment: Could be that your computation requires too much time and is being terminated by the "watchdog timer".

Comment: @JaredHoberock Is there a way I can check that?

Comment: Not sure, but you could refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497685/how-do-you-get-around-the-maximum-cuda-run-time) for some ideas.

Comment: It seems like on Windows you have to mess with the registry which can be dangerous.  It says the watchdog timer is only for a graphics card attached to a monitor.  My laptop has both the intel hd4000 and nvidia card. Is there some way to run the program on the nvidia while the integrated graphics takes care of the display?

Answer (score 2):

I had that kind of error with thrust when I forgot to adjust the `Properties` of the project to my CUDA card compute capability

`Configuration Properties > CUDA C\C++ > Device > Code Generation` change `compute_10,sm_10` to your GPU compute capability

For Nvidia card with 2.1 compute capability it will be `compute_20,sm_21`

Comment: I found it to be an error with the Windows watchdog timer timing out. I,m already using sm_20. Does 2.1 happen to deal with that?

Comment: What is the cause for Windows watchdog timer to time out exactly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure just that Windows will cause the nvidia driver to crash if it doesn't get a response from the device in time. Or something along those lines