# Why does repeating the exact same task within an OpenCL kernel more times cause it to crash?

Tags: c, arrays, opencl

I've written an OpenCL program in C in order to take advantage of my GPU for parallel processing, and I've run into an issue where the display driver crashes under certain calling conditions when running one of my kernels.  I've created a new stripped-down program that demonstrates the same behavior.

Essentially I allocate a linear array on the GPU and then launch a kernel, in which each thread will increment each value in a single nonoverlapping 'row' of the array of fixed size, according to its global thread ID.

I have a for loop wrapping this task which causes it to be repeated a number of times - however, each repetition, I reset the pointer to memory to the same starting value, so the inner loop should be performing exactly the same task each iteration of the outer loop.

The odd behavior is that the program runs with no apparent errors (and the output looks correct) when run with between 1 and 958 repetitions of the outer loop.  However, if this number is increased to anything above 958, the display driver crashes and is recovered.  Oddly, this doesn't result in an error returned by `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` or the subsequent `clFinish()`.

Here's the kernel in question:

```
__kernel void testKernel(__global unsigned int* arr)
{
    // OVERRIDE ARGS
    unsigned int numReps = 958;
    unsigned int numRows = 1000;
    unsigned int rowLength = 676;

    // Make sure thread index is in-bounds
    if( get_global_id(0) < numRows )
    {           
        __global unsigned int* arrPtr;
        __global unsigned int* arrInitPtr = arr + (get_global_id(0) * rowLength);
        unsigned int i, j;
        unsigned int tmp;

        for( i = 0; i < numReps; ++i )
        {
            // Reset the array pointer to the first element in this thread's row
            arrPtr = arrInitPtr;

            for( j = 0; j < rowLength; ++j )
            {
                // Increment value in the row
                tmp = *arrPtr;
                *arrPtr = tmp + 1;
                // Advance pointer to the next value
                ++arrPtr;                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've hard-coded the number of rows and row length to avoid any possible mistakes in parameter-passing and simplify things further.

I allocate the buffer (passed in to the kernel as `arr`) and enqueue the kernel as follows:

```
size_t numThreads = 1000;
unsigned int rowLength = 676;
size_t arrLength = rowLength * numThreads;
cl_mem arr_d = clCreateBuffer(gpuContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, arrLength * sizeof(unsigned int), NULL, &clErr);
if( clErr != CL_SUCCESS )
{
    printf("Error: Failed to allocate buffer on device.\n");
    exit(2);
}

clSetKernelArg(testKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &arr_d);


clErr = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(gpuCmdQueue, testKernel, 1, NULL, &numThreads, &numThreads, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

My first instinct is of course that `arrPtr` is being incremented beyond the boundaries of the array - however, I don't think this should be happening based on the for loop conditional and the fact that when I examine memory after copying the array back to the host, no values outside of the array appear to have been modified.  For clarity, in my original program I initialize every value in the array to zero beforehand, but I left that out of this example program since it doesn't seem relevant to my problem.

I am positive that the memory access to `arrPtr` is out-of-bounds somehow - I don't see any other way for this to be crashing.  However, my array is large enough, and I check the global thread ID before making any accesses, so even if my thread pool size were too large, that shouldn't be a problem.

I assume that the specific boundaries of the failure (958 - 959) are fairly arbitrary since they don't directly correspond to any of my parameters.  The added repetitions must be exposing an underlying indexing problem.  However, it's odd in that case that it's so repeatable with those values.  I've also tried reducing one from various parameters in order to look for off-by-one errors, to no avail.

For reference, I'm using nVidia's 64-bit implementation of OpenCL (CUDA 6.0 drivers) with a GeForce 770 under Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks for any responses!  I've tried to be specific but didn't want this to become too long - if you have any questions or want to see my full OpenCL setup code, please just let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you are experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939843/large-for-loop-crashing-in-geforce-nvidia-gt-610/17950685#17950685

Comment: I think you're right - I didn't come across that question in my searching, but it sounds like the perfect explanation for this.  I'm not sure what the ettiquette is here, but I'd be happy to accept that as an answer or to delete this as a duplicate or what have you.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, because he didn't answer now for a year or so, and it should be accepted, I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's old, but whatever... From the comment:

Windows has a watchdog timer mechanism that restarts the display driver if it appears to become unresponsive. I find that if my kernel runs for more than a few seconds, the timer will trip and restart the display driver. The only solution I know of is to break up the kernel execution into segments of one or two seconds each and run them sequentially.
(I got kinda this error, so this still seems to be true)